# Jsoup Remove Child Text From Result

Tags: jsoup, element

```
Elements runningTime = movdet.select("table.infobox.vevent tr th:contains(Running time) + td");
Elements sing = movdet.select("h1#firstHeading.firstHeading");

 String running = runningTime.text();
 String heading = sing.text();

        System.out.println(heading + " " + running );

<tr>
<th scope="row" style="white-space:nowrap;padding-right:0.65em;">
<div style="padding:0.1em 0;line-height:1.2em;white-space:normal;">Running time</div>
</th>
<td style="line-height:1.3em;">97 minutes<sup id="cite_ref-1" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-1">[1]</a></sup></td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to get td text without the 'sup' element without any success.
what Am getting is :

run:
run:

1. L.A. Confidential (film) Curtis Hanson 138 minutes
2. L.A. Story Mick Jackson 98 minutes[1]
3. L.I.E. Michael Cuesta 97 minutes[1]
4. L.O.R.D: Legend of Ravaging Dynasties Guo Jingming 117 minutes[2]
5. L'arma Pasquale Squitieri
6. L'ora legale Ficarra e Picone 95 min
7. La Bamba (film) Luis Valdez 108 minutes
8. La La La at Rock Bottom Nobuhiro Yamashita 103 minutes

So i want to get rid of "[1]". I have tried ownText() method and it doesn't work.
Anyone with an idea of how to deal with this?

Comment: Can you post a running sample?

Answer (score 0):

```
Elements singm = doc.select("div#content.mw-body");
            singm.select("sup").remove();
```

I had to remove all the superscripts.